# Ждать выполнения потоков Java

Tags: java, concurrency

Добрый день!
У меня стоит задача сделать **ScheduledThreadPool**, запихнуть в него **execute** потоки, и остановить текущий поток пока все остальные не выполняться или *они не зависнут*. Я имею ввиду, что может возникнуть такая ситуация, что хотя бы 1 поток прервется(выполняется именно **Runnable**, исключений не выкидывает), необходимо в этом случае, что бы сотальные доработали и основной поток продолжил выполнение. Я пробовал **awaitTerminator**, но тот не реагирует на прервавшийся поток и продолжает ждать тайм-аута. Есть какие решения еще? Спасибо

Comment: Зачем использовать ScheduledThreadPool и дожидаться выполнения задач в основном потоке? Разве смысл Scheduled не в том, чтобы задачи выполнялись по расписанию? Может быть вас интересует вопрос, как запустить N задач и долждаться их выполнения в основном потоке?

Comment: да меня именно это инетересует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оформите ваши задачи в виде [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) и используйте метод [invokeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

```
List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<Future>();
futures.add(f1);
futures.add(fn);
List<Future> results = executor.invokeAll(futures); //блокирует основной поток в ожидании завершения всех задач.
```

При необходимости можно в вызове `invokeAll` можно устнаовить таймаут на ожидание заверешеня. Затем пробегаетесь по всем результатам. Те экземпляры `Future`, которые завершились корректно, вернут `true` при вызове `isDone`, а результат можно получить методом `get`.

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятна ваша задача.

Наверное так можно ошибки обработать в потоке:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }       
});
t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("exception " + e + " from thread " + t);
    }
});
t.start();
```

[Нашел здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662539/java-thread-exceptions)

Comment: я имел ввиду, что мне необходимо что бы главный поток после запуска всех остальных потоков(**ScheduledThreadPool.execute**)остановился и ждал пока они не завершаться. Но только есть одна проблема, вдруг какие-то потоки прервутся,а остальные проработают. Завершится ли главный поток? Есть предложение испольовать **awaitTerminator**